# Javascript syntax in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a ReactJS render function where I iterate over an array to display the contents like this:

```
render() {
    let object = eval('('+this.props.objectData+')');
    let cd = object.objColAliases;
    return (
        <div>
            {
                cd.map(o=>{
                    return <p>{o}</p>
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

This code is working but at the console I have an warning:

> react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list
> should have a unique "key" prop.

, the warning makes sense, map is used to iterate over Maps not over simple arrays.

So I try to iterate like a normal array, like this:

```
render() {
    let object = eval('('+this.props.objectData+')');
    let cd = object.objColAliases;
    return (
        <div>
            {
                for (let i = 0; i < cd.length; i++) {
                    return <p>{o}</p>
                }
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

But now I have a syntax error on the line with "for (let i = 0; i < cd.length; i++)".
How do I write the correct code in this context?

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-spence-tjb8k1) is a sandbox with the problem.

[image]

Comment: `map` _is_ used to iterate over simple arrays. The interpolated JS in JSX **must** be an expression. Why not just add the key prop?

Comment: To get rid of the warning, You can change your code like `{cd.map((o, index)=>{ return <p key={index}>{o}</p>})}` . Make note `index` . Forked sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/for-in-render-forked-t57him

Comment: I'm a little concerned about `eval('('+this.props.objectData+')');`. What is it mean to do?

Comment: this.props.objectData is a JSON string and I transform to a object using eval, is not fine like this?

Comment: `JSON.parse(this.props.objectData)` would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a unique `key` tag to elements returned inside the `.map`, s

```js
render() {
    let object = eval('('+this.props.objectData+')');
    let cd = object.objColAliases;
    return (
        <div>
            {
                cd.map(o=>{
                    return <p key={o.id}>{o}</p>
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

If `o` does not have a unique property, you can also use the index, like so

```js
render() {
    let object = eval('('+this.props.objectData+')');
    let cd = object.objColAliases;
    return (
        <div>
            {
                cd.map((o, index) =>{
                    return <p key={index}>{o}</p>
                })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `key` prop to the parent tag in the map if it's unique:

```
<div>{cd.map((o) => <p key={o}>{o}</p>)}</div>
```

If it's not unique, you can use `index` as a `key` when mapping:

```
<div>{cd.map((o, index) => <p key={index}>{o}</p>)}</div>
```

But, read the documentation first, because using the index as a key is not recommended: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html